# Is a hard drive under direct I/O still randomly accessible?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, io

A hard drive is randomly accessible.

On Linux, when performing direct I/O i.e. raw I/O on a block device file (such as for hard drive) or regular file by passing `O_DIRECT` flag to `open()`, is it only sequentially accessible or can it still be randomly accessible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`O_DIRECT`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) tries to minimise cache effects on I/O performed with the corresponding file descriptor, it has nothing to do with sequentiality. You can perform random access as usual using [`lseek`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html), if the underlying device supports that.

Comment: Thanks. How does an underlying device support random access, and not support it?

Comment: Pipes for example can’t seek; I think terminal devices can’t either. See the linked manpage: “Some devices are incapable of seeking and POSIX does not specify which devices must support `lseek()`.”