# Does raw I/O bypass some or most services provided by the driver?

Tags: linux, drivers, io

Operating System Concepts by Abraham Silberschatz 9th 2012 says

> Raw I/O **bypasses all the ﬁlesystem services**, such as ﬁle I/O demand paging, ﬁle locking, prefetching, space allocation, ﬁle names, and directories.
>
> ...
>
> Unfortunately, **no operating-system services** are then performed on this device.

Does raw I/O also bypass some or most services provided by the driver?

What kinds of services provided by the drivers does raw I/O bypass? If I understand Stephen [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473457/how-is-a-sequentially-accessible-device-made-randomly-accessible?noredirect=1#comment864807_473457) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473451/674) correctly, raw I/O doesn't bypass random accessibility provided by a driver to a sequentially-addressable-only device, but bypasses buffer/cache provided by a driver?

Does it change the device driver to a more primitive one with much less services?

Note you can perform raw I/O by `open()` with `O_DIRECT`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `O_DIRECT` bypasses caches.  It does not bypass the driver.

Using `O_DIRECT` on a block device bypasses the kernel "buffer cache".  "buffer cache" is not part of the driver.

Using `O_DIRECT` on a regular file - i.e. a file which is not a device special file - is a request to bypass the kernel "page cache".  The "page cache" is not part of the filesystem, but it is not part of the driver either.

On older OS's, file IO may be cached in two places - both page cache and buffer cache.  If this is the case, `O_DIRECT` should bypass both caches.

On Linux and many other modern Unix-likes, buffer cache may actually depend on page cache.  They are described as having a Unified Buffer Cache.  A significant feature is that it avoids caching file IO in two different places.  Therefore it uses memory more efficiently.  Different people seem to use conflicting definitions.  Some people say there is no buffer cache, only a page cache.

Even when an OS avoids caching file IO in two different places, it might not guarantee to make the cache used for file IO consistent with the cache used when accessing the block device file.

---

(`O_DIRECT` cannot work on Linux `tmpfs`, because `tmpfs` is little more than a wrapper around the page cache and the directory cache.  It has been suggested that `tmpfs` could allow `O_DIRECT` to succeed, and simply ignore it, to improve compatibility.  Therefore I would not say that `O_DIRECT` is guaranteed to bypass the page cache.)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think he means the same thing as O_DIRECT; I think he's referring to accessing a block device such as /dev/sda. Opening /dev/sda will bypass "ﬁle locking, prefetching, space allocation, ﬁle names, and directories" - so it's bypassed the filesystem, but not the block device driver.